# What is the meaning of 'trailing newline is stripped'?

Tags: newline

This is a term I found in a programming tutorial. What does it mean?

Comment: @D-side I've read about this thing a couple days ago, so I don't remember the context. But if I remember correctly, it have something to do with the \n, \b etc. of programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would normally refer to something like parsing lines of text, it describes the `newline` or `carriage return` being removed from the end of the line.

The `newline` is often invisible to the end user, but represents a command to end a line and start a new one to the computer. Depending on your OS or programming language, newlines may be represented by different characters.
(ref: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n )

Often a newline would be `\n` and a carriage return `\r` and they would often occur together `\n\r` to indicate the end of the current line, and the return or the caret to the beginning of the next line.

It may be undesirable to strip the trailing newline as you may need it reproduce a block of text as a user created it. By stripping the newline, the spacing or layout of the text may be ruined and all sentences / paragraphs may be merged into one large block.

Answer (score 1):

It means that new line character '\n' at the end of a string is removed.
For example, in the command line output you ask a user to input something:

```
"""
C:\Users\Admin>
Please, input something: _
"""
```

And user's input will start from the place where the underscore character is. Otherwise, (if not 'trailing newline is stripped'), user's input will start from the new line. (See where the underscore character is).

```
"""
C:\Users\Admin>
Please, input something:
_
"""
```